# Can't connect to IBOutlet from TabView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a NSWindow with tab views, inside one of the tabs is a NSTable. I am trying to connect from File's Owner to my table (`IBOutlet NSTabView *addedAccountsTable;`), and I can't! It keeps on connecting me to the TabView it's in. Why?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the table and then dragging a referencing outlet back to File's Owner?

Comment: Is File's Owner the object that has the outlet for your table?

Comment: ^ yes, file's owner has the IBOutlet for the table declared in header.

Comment: You know that NSTabView != NSTableView, right?

Comment: you're right! I misspelled it doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your outlet from `NSTabView` to `NSTableView`; you'll likely be able to make the connection.